# Derived class from numpy array does not play well with matrix and masked array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, subclassing

I am trying to subclass a numpy ndarray but I am not able to get right the operations with other numpy types such as masked array or matrix. It seems to me that the **__array_priority__** is not being honored. As an example, I have created a dummy class that mimicks the important aspects:

```
import numpy as np

class C(np.ndarray):

    __array_priority__ = 15.0

    def __mul__(self, other):
        print("__mul__")
        return 42

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        print("__rmul__")
        return 42
```

Operations between my class and *normal* ndarray work as expected:

```
>>> c1 = C((3, 3))
>>> o1 = np.ones((3, 3))
>>> print(o1 * c1)
__mul__
42
>>> print(c1 * o1)
__rmul__
42
```

But, when I try to operate with matrix (or masked arrays) the array priority is not respected.

```
>>> m = np.matrix((3, 3))
>>> print(c1 * m)
__mul__
42
>>> print(m * c1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 330, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

It seems to me that the way ufuncs are wrapped for matrix and masked arrays do not honor array priority. Is this the case? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Actually, the error message is given because they are not aligned, since `np.matrix((3, 3))` is not the same as `np.asmatrix(np.ones((3, 3)))`. However, the problem still persists except that `m * c1` is the one that isn't working.

Comment: @GustavLarsson Thanks for spotting that. I fixed it and added more info in the motivation.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to subclass `np.matrixib.defmatrix.matrix`:

```
class C(np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix):

    __array_priority__ = 15.0

    def __mul__(self, other):
        print("__mul__")
        return 42

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        print("__rmul__")
        return 4
```

In this case the priority is also higher then a `np.ndarray` and your multiplication methods are always called.

As added in the comments, you can subclass from multiple classes in case you need interoperability:

```
class C(np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix, np.ndarray):
```

Comment: This works nicely, but my classes are better described by ndarray than matrix. Additionally, my class should interoperate with ndarray, matrix and masked darray. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Try using this approach and see if the interoperation is achieved, if not, you can subclass from more than one class, doing like: `class C(np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix, np.ndarray):`, for example...

Comment: I have redefined the class as `class C(np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix, np.ma.core.MaskedArray, np.ndarray):`. It is ugly but it seems to work, I still need more test cases. I am now trying to do the same for a class that wraps an array (without subclassing). Again, it works fine when multipliying by a ndarray but not for anything else.

Comment: I think the solution for your case is doing the multiple subclassing when subclassing only from `np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix` does not work.